# Search for matrix field in a global set

Tags: matrix, search, globals

I've set up a global set "attachmentGlobals" with a matrix field inside named "globalFiles". This matrix has only one block "files" which has a text field "fileId" and an Asset field "fileAsset".

I would like to retrieve a specific row searching for the "fileId" content.

I've triyed in those ways:

**Test 1:**

```
attachmentGlobals.globalFiles.fileId('sitelogo')
```

Return me an Error saying no method "fileId" is available

**Test 2:**

```
attachmentGlobals.globalFiles.find('fileId:sitelogo')
```

No error, but no results

**Test 3:**

```
attachmentGlobals.globalFiles.search('fileId:sitelogo')
```

No error, but no results

I've search Craft documentation and some examples on Stack Exchange, but nothing seems to help.

In the first place, is this possible? or were am I wrong?

Thank you in advance.

*PS: I know this issue could be solved using only assets fields, but I would like to know if is possible to search for matrix fields by filed content.*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, (currently) the only way to filter matrix blocks is to use the [`type`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields#filtering-by-block-type) method to filter by block type or to limit the amount of returned matrix models with [`limit`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields#adjusting-the-limit).

Here's what I'd do:

```
{% set searchString = 'sitelogo' %}

{# Search for potential matrix blocks #}
{% set foundBlocks = attachmentGlobals.globalFiles.type('files').search(searchString) %}

{# Loop through the result and output the right one #}
{% for foundBlock in foundBlocks %}

    {% if foundBlock.fileId == searchString %}
        <img src="{{ foundBlock.fileAsset.first.url }}" alt="{{ foundBlock.fileAsset.first.title }}">
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

You can't use `search('fileId:sitelogo')`, because that would filter for entries with  `fileId:sitelogo` and not entries with a matrix block `fileId:sitelogo`.

Comment: How would you do that in a plugin?

Comment: @David sorry, can't help you with a plugin solution. I've still no experience with php5 (yet)! Have a look at the [methods available for MatrixBlockModel](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/MatrixBlockModel#public-methods), you should be able to do the exact same conditional in your plugin. If you need further help, better ask a new question because I don't think many will notice your comment.