# How to search for content in a specific Matrix field?

Tags: matrix, search, filter

I'm not entirely sure how to search a *specific* Matrix field for a given bit of content. I can use:

```
{% for cta in entry.homeCtas.search('"Lorem Ipsum"') %}
    <h1>{{ cta.ctaTitle }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

to find any Matrix rows with "Lorem Ipsum" (not in a specific field). But when I try something like this:

```
{% for cta in entry.homeCtas.search('ctaTitle:"Lorem Ipsum"') %}
    <h1>{{ cta.ctaTitle }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

It returns nothing. Is my field syntax incorrect? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think this could help: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2104/125

Comment: Hm, I'm not certain that confirms/denies an ability to search a specific field within a Matrix, though. The comment at the end ("You can't use search('fileId:sitelogo'), because that would filter for entries with fileId:sitelogo and not entries with a matrix block fileId:sitelogo.") makes it sound like this user is explaining why the author's original code doesn't work. I don't see anything about if it's possible or not.

Comment: There is no such thing as a matrixcriteriamodel. Only type and limit filter is possible (at least that's the only filters documented).

Comment: This didn't help, Aaron?

Comment: Sorry, carlcs. Thanks for clarifying that for me! Hopefully one day Matrix will have this level of support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'm not clear of is if you are asking if you can query for entries that have a matrix field that contains x, or if you just asking if you can search within a matrix field of an entry that has already been returned by a query.

If it is the later, the following solution would work. This isn't a feature of Craft, but a feature of Twig. Thus, implementing it won't save on queries or anything, but it will help you filter the results returned by Craft.

Twig has a feature that allows you to apply a condition in addition to the for loop. It is documented [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition).

```
{% for cta in entry.homeCtas if cta.ctaTitle == "Lorem Ipsum" %}
    <h1>{{ cta.ctaTitle }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, Wes. I should have clarified this further. I _was_ working with the latter situation. I'll give this a shot!